# What is the meaning of "ន"?

Tags: grammar, symbols

I found this symbol (ន) as part of one of my fonts, but when I tried to do research on it, I came up with pretty much nothing. This has been nagging at me for a while, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%9E%93

Comment: @Drossel Thank you for that link.

Comment: Did you find this symbol in English text?

Comment: @Mitch No. I think that it is in Sanskrit or some other language. If you have more questions, check out the link posted by Drossel above

Comment: @AnonyMouse Why are you asking on ELU then? If it is a character that you found in the middle of English text, then it is totally on-topic (even if it turns out to be in another language). But otherwise, if you just found it in a code table or in a font list (tell us what font then), then it is way off topic. You should ask this on a technical site. Also, did you do a google search first?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about English.

Comment: @Mitch Not so. 'I found this symbol (ន) mentioned in a question on the 'English Explained' website; what does it mean?' is 'in the middle of English text', but this does not make this question on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ន is a letter in the Cambodian Alphabet.

1. The 20th letter of the Cambodian Alphabet (Khmer)
2. It can be masculine (ន) or feminine (នា)
3. It can also be used as the Khmer script form of Na (He, that, it, or not)